# Richtext Box-TextChanged Even and checking spaces in current line

Tags: c#, events, richtextbox, textchanged

Is that possible to check the no. of spaces in current line of the richtextbox with its text changes event...
for example

```
lin1: word1 word2 word3
lin2: word1 word2 word3 word4

when i type space after word3 it shows me message that you cannot enter word4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use this TextBox extension and apply it to your RichTextBox(see code below, complete version findable [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/10/19/C--Get-current-Caret-Line-and-Column-in-a.aspx))

```
public class TextBoxExtension : TextBox
{
 public TextBoxExtension (){ }

 public int CurrentLineIndex
 {
    get { return this.GetLineFromCharIndex(this.SelectionStart) + 1; }
 }
}
```

Then do the following:

```
int maxWordsAllowed = 4;

private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
    //This get the space character count in your current line 
    if (myRichTextBox.Lines[myRichTextBox.CurrentLineIndex].Split(' ').Length - 1) > maxWordsAllowed )
      MessageBox.Show("Reached Maximum Words for that line");    
}
```